# How to redirect page without caching the redirection in JavaScript/ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, server-side-rendering

I have this logic in my TypeScript ReactJS SSR App:

```js
public login() {
  let error: boolean = false
  const isLoggedIn: boolean = doSomeLogicHereLikeBackendCheck()
  if(isLoggedIn) {
    window.location.href = "/home" // this is getting cached (302 - Cached)
  } else {
    // stay in "/login"
    error = true
  }  
}


...

// call login
login()
```

Now,I use Chrome at the moment. When User successfully logged in, I redirect him via `window.location.href` to `/home`. That is OK. However, problem starts after user logged out. When user logged out, If he try to login again using `/login` path, he immediately redirected to `/home` instead of login page. (Of course he did not logged in just redirected back to home). I inspected the network and it seems Chrome does caching my **redirect**?!

How to make sure I redirect users only if they logged in? How can I make this redirection cache-free? So that if user revisit `/login` page again I will show the login page (*if its not logged in*) **OR** redirect to `/home` myself if logged in... I want to control redirections.

I also tried `window.location.replace('/home')`. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by specifying `no-cache`:

```
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store'
  response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
  response.headers['Expires'] = 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the date to the url.

```
var url = "https://example.com/cachedResource";
window.location = url + (url[url.length-1] === "?" ? "" : "?") + new Date().getTime();
```

if url last character is "?" adds the date. Else adds the "?" before add the date.
This way you can avoid cache without server changes.

PD: I'm 100% sure you can do this with less code.